# Mindbody Api , GetClassSchedulesRequest

Tags: api, mindbody

the operation GetClassSchedulesRequest , returns a list of schedules , but it does not return class status (isCancelled,isAvaialble,Substitute).

if i add "ClassSchedules.Classes" to the Fields Paramater , it returns all the classes inside that response along with schedule data .

Comment: did you solve your issue?

Comment: Hello there , unfortunately no .  i wanted to check availability , substitute class teacher of particular class in GetClassSchedules()  api response .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but if you're looking for class statuses, then you need to use the `GetClasses` API call in the [`ClassService`](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Documentation/ClassService) in order to get them.

Comment: Hello there , unfortunately no . i wanted to check availability , substitute class teacher of particular class in GetClassSchedules() api response

Comment: @coolfuturefbiagent I know that you can determine availability of the class via the `GetClasses` API (you'll be able to call methods like `isAvailable`, `isCanceled` on the class), and I believe you also have a `substitute` method that can tell you if a substitute teacher has been assigned for a class (returns a boolean).

Comment: is i can get that Details with GetClasses() , but the thing is , it will be too slow if i wanted to check status,substitute teacher on every class id returned by GetClassSchedules()

Comment: @coolfuturefbiagent I'm not sure you'll be able to get the kind of efficiency you want out of the API (I've found it difficult to extract information efficiently in the past), but if you do end up solving your problem, please add an answer.

Comment: yes , is there anyway to find substitute class teacher name ?